# Laravel 8.x - Best way to create duplicate entries in mysql

Tags: sql, laravel

I have a project in which I need to create 'n' number of duplicates of a record. This involves duplicating records in a child table. Right now i am INSERTing the duplicate parent record and then INSERT corresponding child records for that table.

My Parent table (portal_programs)
[image]

My Parent table (portal_programs)

[image]

```
try {

            if ($programid) {
                $programobj = Programs::find($programid);
                if (!empty($eventobj)) {
                    
                    $duplicateprogramobj = new Programs();
                    $duplicateprogramobj->title = $programobj->title;
                    .
                    .
                    .
                   $duplicateprogramobj->save();         
                    
                    $productsobj = \App\Models\Product::select('*')
                                   ->where('program_id','=',$programid)->get();
                    
                    foreach($productsobj as $product)
                    {
                        
                        $duplicateprod = new \App\Models\Product();
                        $duplicateprod->program_id = $duplicateprogramobj->id;
                        .
                        .
                        .
                        $duplicateprod->save();        
                                
                        
                    }
                            
                   
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            Log::critical($ex->getMessage());
        }
```

Is there any better/efficient way to achieve the same?

Comment: If the code is functional it's fine. If you're trying to achieve a specific design philosophy concerning your code style, I think that's a different question.

Comment: It's a design question

Comment: I can't comment about the efficiency, but you could reduce the number of lines of code by using eloquent's `replicate` method to make the copy of the model. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#replicating-models